# Apache Strom resets stats after random period of time

Tags: apache-storm

I have topology with one bolt and one spout. It works well, but sometimes all statistics disappears and starts to count from zero. I don't restart supervisors, nimbus or anything else. What can be the cause of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in huge amount of messages receiving by Storm. The solution is to configure topology.max.spout.pending in order to limit number of messages in the system.